# Terraform retrieving existing GCP secret as Data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-secret-manager

Trying to implement a Data Module for referencing a 'Robot Account' for Terraform.

I get the folowing errors:

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on main.tf line 7, in provider "google":
   7:   credentials   = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.secret

A data resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret" has not been
declared in the root module.
```

```
Error: Reference to undeclared input variable

  on datamodule\KeydataModule.tf line 3, in data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret":
   3:   secret = "${var.Terra_Auth}"

An input variable with the name "Terra_Auth" has not been declared. This
variable can be declared with a variable "Terra_Auth" {} block.
```

With the following **main.tf**:

```
module "KeydataModule" {
  source = "./datamodule"

}

provider "google" {
  credentials   = data.google_secret_manager_secret_version.secret
  project       = "KubeProject"
  region        = "us-central1"
  zone          = "us-central1-c"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  name         = "terraform-instance"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "ubuntu-cloud/ubuntu-1804-lts"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    # A default network is created for all GCP projects
    network       = google_compute_network.vpc_network.self_link
    access_config {
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_network" "vpc_network" {
  name                    = "terraform-network"
  auto_create_subnetworks = "true"
}
```

The **keydataModule.tf**:

```
data "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret" {
  provider = google-beta
  secret = "${var.Terra_Auth}"
}
```

The following **variables.tf** for creating the 'Terra Auth' variable:

```
variable "Terra_Auth" {
   type = string
   description = "Access Key for Terraform Service Account" 
}
```

And finally a **terraform.tfvars** file, which in this case houses the secret name within my GCP account:

```
Terra_Auth = "Terraform_GCP_Account_Secret"
```

Comment: What problems are you having? Does it error? If so can you edit your question to include the full error output please? If it doesn't error but doesn't do what you want can you share what it does and how that doesn't do what you want please?

Comment: Your module needs to output the value of the data source, then you can access it in the main.tf via module.KeydataModule.whatever_you_named_it.

Comment: Thanks @sethvargo . Would that mean the 'credentials' under 'provider' would be filled with the module.keydatamodule.whatever_i_name_it? :)

Comment: Terraform only has access to resources and data sources defined at the root. The "google_secret_manager_secret_version` resource is inside a module, so you cannot access it from the root. Your module needs to define an output with that value.

Comment: @sethvargo, got some time to retry this, still stuck.

I referenced the data module in main.tf and put the credentials as:
module.KeydataModule.PWsecret

Referencing the output in the module:
output "PWsecret" {
  value = google_secret_manager_secret_version.secret
  sensitive = true
}

The error still states 'secret' in google_secret_manager_version has not been declared.